# Join Multple CTEs in SQL - Error " Invalid Table Name"

Tags: sql, oracle, common-table-expression

I am trying to get my three CTEs to join and plus one more table . Below is what I am doing but I am missing something . I have looked up same error and I am being told I am missing "," but I did that and still the same error. The error is "Invalid Table Name". Any help is much appreciated as always .

Side note - I did run each CTE and each one ran perfectly by themselves and as single CTE, its when I try and put them together I get the error .

```
--------1. CTE  

WITH

Memb AS (
Select *
 From icue.HSC_MBR_COV mbc
     Where mbc.POL_ISS_ST_CD = 'PA' 
  And  (mbc.LOB_TYP_ID = '12' OR mbc.CLM_PLTFM_ID  = 'A9')

  Union 


  Select *
 From icue.HSC_MBR_COV mbc
     Where mbc.POL_ISS_ST_CD = 'NJ' 
  And  (mbc.LOB_TYP_ID = '12' OR mbc.CLM_PLTFM_ID  = 'A9')                    

),
  --select * from Memb


----------- 2.CTE Fax Flag 
 With 

  Fax_Flag AS(

SELECT Distinct
  cmt.CNTC_NM As Provider_Name,
  cmt.FAX_NBR,

  CASE When cmt.FAX_NBR ='201-553-7889' THEN 'Yes'
     ELSE 'No'
       END  AS Fax_Flag

   From  icue.cmnct_trans cmt
    Where cmt.CNTC_NM ='CHILDRENS HOSP PHILADELPHIA'

   ),   

   --Select * From Fax_Flag


   ------------3. CTE  Letter Flag

  With 

   Letter_Sent AS(

   Select Distinct
   act.Actv_strt_dttm AS Fax_Date,
   act.ACTV_TYP_ID,


    CASE When ACTV_TYP_ID ='5' THEN 'Yes'
     ELSE 'No'
       END  AS Letter_Flag

  From icue.actv act
     Where trunc(act.actv_strt_dttm) between to_date('19-FEB-2018','DD-MON-YYYY') and to_date('06-MAR-2018','DD-MON-YYYY')

),

  Select * From Letter_sent



---------FINAL - I want to put all the CTE together

Select Distinct

    mb.Fst_Nm AS First_Name,
    mb.Lst_Nm AS Last Name,
    mbc.Member_Policy_State,
    mbc.mbr_id AS Memeber_ID,
    cmt.HSC_ID AS Auth_Number,
    cmt.Fax_Number,
    cmt.Provider_Name,
    act.Fax_Date,
    act.Letter_Flag,
    cmt.Fax_Flag

    From icue.mbr mb


 Inner Join Memb mbc     --- CTE 1
  On mb.Mbr_ID = mbc.Mbr_ID

 Inner Join Fax_Flag cmt   ---- CTE 2
  On cmt.HSC_ID = cmt.HSC_ID

 Inner Join Letter_Sent act ---- CTE 3
  On act.Mbr_ID = mbc.Mbr_ID
```

update *** I did try and join the two CTEs below, but I keep getting an "Table/view does not exists" error

```
   --------1. CTE  Bring in only PA and NJ market

With

Memb AS (
Select Distinct 
  mbc.Hsc_Id                                   AS  Auth_Number,
  mbc.POL_ISS_ST_CD                            AS  Policy_State

 From icue.HSC_MBR_COV mbc
     Where mbc.POL_ISS_ST_CD = 'PA' 
  And  (mbc.LOB_TYP_ID = '12' OR mbc.CLM_PLTFM_ID  = 'A9')

  Union 


  Select Distinct 
    mbc.hsc_id                         AS Auth_Number,
    mbc.POL_ISS_ST_CD                  AS  Policy_State

 From icue.HSC_MBR_COV mbc
     Where mbc.POL_ISS_ST_CD = 'NJ' 
  And  (mbc.LOB_TYP_ID = '12' OR mbc.CLM_PLTFM_ID  = 'A9')  



),
  ---select * from Memb


----------- 2.CTE Fax Flag 


  Fax_Flag AS(

SELECT Distinct
  cmt.CNTC_NM                     As Provider_Name,
  cmt.FAX_NBR                     AS Fax_Number,
  cmt.HSC_ID                      AS Auth_Number,


  CASE When cmt.FAX_NBR ='201-553-7889' THEN 'Yes'
     ELSE 'No'
       END  AS Fax_Flag

   From icue.cmnct_trans cmt

  Left Join Memb mbc
   On cmt.hsc_id = mbc.Hsc_Id
     And cmt.CNTC_NM ='CHILDRENS HOSP PHILADELPHIA'

   )

   Select * From Fax_Flag
```

Comment: Sorry about that did not realize . I am using Oracle and this is my second week with it .

Answer (score 3):

Try removing the 2nd and 3rd `WITH` and the comma at the end of the 3rd CTE

```
--------1. CTE  

WITH

Memb AS (
Select *
 From icue.HSC_MBR_COV mbc
     Where mbc.POL_ISS_ST_CD = 'PA' 
  And  (mbc.LOB_TYP_ID = '12' OR mbc.CLM_PLTFM_ID  = 'A9')

  Union 


  Select *
 From icue.HSC_MBR_COV mbc
     Where mbc.POL_ISS_ST_CD = 'NJ' 
  And  (mbc.LOB_TYP_ID = '12' OR mbc.CLM_PLTFM_ID  = 'A9')                    

),
  --select * from Memb


----------- 2.CTE Fax Flag 
--- With 

  Fax_Flag AS(

SELECT Distinct
  cmt.CNTC_NM As Provider_Name,
  cmt.FAX_NBR,

  CASE When cmt.FAX_NBR ='201-553-7889' THEN 'Yes'
     ELSE 'No'
       END  AS Fax_Flag

   From  icue.cmnct_trans cmt
    Where cmt.CNTC_NM ='CHILDRENS HOSP PHILADELPHIA'

   ),   

   --Select * From Fax_Flag


   ------------3. CTE  Letter Flag

---  With 

   Letter_Sent AS(

   Select Distinct
   act.Actv_strt_dttm AS Fax_Date,
   act.ACTV_TYP_ID,


    CASE When ACTV_TYP_ID ='5' THEN 'Yes'
     ELSE 'No'
       END  AS Letter_Flag

  From icue.actv act
     Where trunc(act.actv_strt_dttm) between to_date('19-FEB-2018','DD-MON-YYYY') and to_date('06-MAR-2018','DD-MON-YYYY')

) -- , Removed the comma



---------FINAL - I want to put all the CTE together

Select Distinct

    mb.Fst_Nm AS First_Name,
    mb.Lst_Nm AS Last Name,
    mbc.Member_Policy_State,
    mbc.mbr_id AS Memeber_ID,
    cmt.HSC_ID AS Auth_Number,
    cmt.Fax_Number,
    cmt.Provider_Name,
    act.Fax_Date,
    act.Letter_Flag,
    cmt.Fax_Flag

    From icue.mbr mb


 Inner Join Memb mbc     --- CTE 1
  On mb.Mbr_ID = mbc.Mbr_ID

 Inner Join Fax_Flag cmt   ---- CTE 2
  On cmt.HSC_ID = cmt.HSC_ID

 Inner Join Letter_Sent act ---- CTE 3
  On act.Mbr_ID = mbc.Mbr_ID
```

Comment: Thanks. I did remove the 2 and 3 rd "with" and the 3rd comma but I am now getting a different error " SQL Command not properly ended"

Comment: @cardonas Did you remove `select * from letter_sent`?

Comment: Yes, I removed the select from the statement but still getting error.. I think it because I don't have CTEs join yet. I am trying to get the two CTEs to run but I can only get the first one to run but not second one once I join them .. I keep getting an error "Table view does not exists" and its referencing  the first CTE view in my second CTE

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it's easier to read code if you lay it out neatly. When I do that I get this:

```
with memb as
     ( select distinct
              mbc.hsc_id as auth_number
            , mbc.pol_iss_st_cd as policy_state
       from   icue.hsc_mbr_cov mbc
       where  mbc.pol_iss_st_cd = 'PA'
       and    (mbc.lob_typ_id = '12' or mbc.clm_pltfm_id = 'A9')
       union
       select distinct
              mbc.hsc_id as auth_number
            , mbc.pol_iss_st_cd as policy_state
       from   icue.hsc_mbr_cov mbc
       where  mbc.pol_iss_st_cd = 'NJ'
       and    (mbc.lob_typ_id = '12' or mbc.clm_pltfm_id = 'A9')
      )
    , fax_flag as
      ( select distinct
               cmt.cntc_nm as provider_name
             , cmt.fax_nbr as fax_number
             , cmt.hsc_id as auth_number
             , case
                   when cmt.fax_nbr = '201-553-7889' then 'Yes'
                   else 'No'
               end as fax_flag
        from   icue.cmnct_trans cmt
               left join memb mbc
                    on  mbc.hsc_id = cmt.hsc_id
                    and cmt.cntc_nm = 'CHILDRENS HOSP PHILADELPHIA' )
select * from fax_flag;
```

That `union` looks odd to me, as the two queries are the same apart from `pol_iss_st_cd`, so why not simply:

```
with memb as
     ( select distinct
              mbc.hsc_id as auth_number
            , mbc.pol_iss_st_cd as policy_state
       from   icue.hsc_mbr_cov mbc
       where  mbc.pol_iss_st_cd in ('PA','NJ')
       and    (mbc.lob_typ_id = '12' or mbc.clm_pltfm_id = 'A9') )
    , fax_flag as
      ( select distinct
               cmt.cntc_nm as provider_name
             , cmt.fax_nbr as fax_number
             , cmt.hsc_id as auth_number
             , case
                   when cmt.fax_nbr = '201-553-7889' then 'Yes'
                   else 'No'
               end as fax_flag
        from   icue.cmnct_trans cmt
               left join memb mbc
                    on  cmt.hsc_id = mbc.hsc_id
                    and cmt.cntc_nm = 'CHILDRENS HOSP PHILADELPHIA' )
select * from fax_flag;
```

That gives me *ORA-00942: table or view does not exist* because I don't have icue.hsc_mbr_cov, but otherwise it looks fine. If you are getting that error, which table is it pointing to and can you query it on its own (just to take `WITH` clause syntax out of the equation).

If this is about the syntax in general, though, we can simplify it to a generic test case:

```
with demo1 (id) as ( select 'X' from dual )
   , demo2 (id) as ( select 'X' from dual )
   , demo3 (id) as ( select 'X' from dual )
select d.dummy
from   dual d
       join demo1 d1 on d1.id = d.dummy
       join demo2 d2 on d2.id = d1.id
       join demo3 d3 on d3.id = d2.id
where  d.dummy = 'X';
```

Comment: Thanks for the housekeeping tip! I do need to work on the layout . I did rerun the code and it turns out one of my joins was incorrect because of an Alias , but I did get it to work. I do appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what I was doing wrong . I was Referencing a column with out Referencing its Alias, since I defined it in the first CTE . Code is below

```
--------1. CTE  Bring in only PA and NJ market

With

Memb AS (
Select Distinct 
  mbc.Hsc_Id                                   AS  Auth_Number,
  mbc.POL_ISS_ST_CD                            AS  Policy_State

 From icue.HSC_MBR_COV mbc
     Where mbc.POL_ISS_ST_CD = 'PA' 
  And  (mbc.LOB_TYP_ID = '12' OR mbc.CLM_PLTFM_ID  = 'A9')

  Union 


  Select Distinct 
    mbc.hsc_id                         AS Auth_Number,
    mbc.POL_ISS_ST_CD                  AS  Policy_State

 From icue.HSC_MBR_COV mbc
     Where mbc.POL_ISS_ST_CD = 'NJ' 
  And  (mbc.LOB_TYP_ID = '12' OR mbc.CLM_PLTFM_ID  = 'A9')  



),
  ---select * from Memb


----------- 2.CTE Fax Flag 


  Fax_Flag AS(

SELECT Distinct
  cmt.CNTC_NM                     As Provider_Name,
  cmt.FAX_NBR                     AS Fax_Number,
  --cmt.HSC_ID                      AS Auth_Number,


  CASE When cmt.FAX_NBR ='201-553-7889' THEN 'Yes'
     ELSE 'No'
       END  AS Fax_Flag

   From Memb mbc

  Left Join icue.cmnct_trans cmt
   On mbc.Auth_Number = cmt.hsc_id ----- needed to update mbc.HSC_ID to mbc.auth_number
     And cmt.CNTC_NM ='CHILDRENS HOSP PHILADELPHIA'

   )

   Select * From Fax_Flag
```